# Windows 2008 R2 Shares Disappear on Reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-share, drobo

Every time I reboot our Windows 2008 R2 server, shared folders are no longer shared. After every reboot, I need to RDC to the server, right click each folder I wish to share, then hit "Properties" and "Sharing." The desired share name is always intact, as are the proper permissions for Owner (always Administrator) and the appropriate R/W access I've previously set for groups and users. But the status shows as "Not Shared." If I press the "Share" button, it thinks for a while with the "This may take a few minutes" message, and then reports complete and the shares can be accessed from network clients again.

But on *every* reboot, I have to do this for *every* shared folder.

I've read about similar issues with iSCSI drives, but all the shares are on a Drobo connected to the server via FireWire and appearing as a local drive to the server (not iSCSI). I suspect the fact that the shares are on a Drobo are contributing to the issue, but I'm stumped as to where to start looking for a long-term fix, rather than a work-around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the issue WERE iSCSI related, the fix would be to have the Server service depend upon the iSCSI initiator service. So is there a service that is responsible for the FireWire connection, on which I could make the Server service depend?

Comment: I've already made my life a LITTLE easier by figuring out that yes, I can simply restart the Server service rather than re-share all the folders. Now I still need to figure out what service the Server service can depend on to avoid even having to do that.

Comment: Check the disk ID, a change will result of the loose of the share, as windows think its another disk.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution!

I went through the currently running services to see if I could find any that looked promising, and found DDService, which is the Drobo Dashboard. I added it as an additional dependency to the Server service by doing the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
sc config LanmanServer depend= SamSS/Srv/DDServer
```

(SamSS and Srv were previous dependencies)

Rebooted the server, and crossed my fingers...

The shares went offline from the client while the server rebooted, then came back about 30 seconds after the server started to respond to pings.

I don't know if there's a better dependent service than DDServer, but it seems to work!

EDIT: All the information to fix this issue is contained in this answer, but I just finished writing up a more detailed description of the cause and fix (along with screen-caps) on my blog here, just in case anyone wants some more hand-holding.

http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2016/01/fix-missing-shares-on-windows-2008-server-reboot-with-drobo/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem only with 2 ReadyNas boxes and a share on my pc for 2008r2 users (so issue is not limited to nas box access).

Since I enabled password access to the Nas boxes, every pc (w7, w8, w10, and server 2008r2 users) all need to authenticate (user/password) after every logon or reboot to connect to nas/pc shares.

I have tried every solution I could find (most are not even related to my problem, as all seem specific to some other program) but the issue is a common complaint on the internet. Windows simply forgets its credentials! Manually entered, enter at time of login (and the save password option is totally useless). Why even bother to have a credentials manager, it only lasts for 1 day. What a joke.

So my solution is to use RoboForm and use it to semi-manually fill in the login each time.

It is now almost 2017 and this problem has been around since before 2010, so I don't think it will ever get fixed.